# Variable To Get User Input Asterisk

Tags: variables, asterisk, voip, ivr, pbx

I am writing an IVR and would like to get the keypad number the user dialled and store in in a variable. Does anyone know if asterisk defines such a channel variable? I cannot seem to find in in any variable lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main practice in dooing ivr

```
 exten => s,1,Background(ivr-file-without-extension);play
 exten => s,2,WaitExten(); wait for input
 exten => 1,1,Noop(1 pressed); do something if 1
 exten => 1,2,Set(result=1);for example set variable
```

Or

```
 exten => s,1,Read(result,ivr-file-without-extension,max_digits);
 exten => s,n,Noop(result=${result});
```

In both variants you can set up ANY variable name, thats why you can't find "magic" variable.

But i highly recommend you first read any single asterisk book for beginners. It is very unlikly you can do working app with your current knowledge(based on question asked).

Answer (score 0):

I actually not clearly about your question.
As you said : "to get the keypad number the user dialled and store in in a variable"
so it very simple

```
exten => _X.,1,Noop(User dialed number: ${EXTEN});
```

So the variable you need is: ${EXTEN}